Need Roadmap/Advice for Career Transition to blockchain
I am 31 years old and don't know anything about blockchain. I want to learn and use blockchain technology in the hydrogen energy sector. Can you provide a roadmap or advice? I want to improve.

Try this one: https://roadmap.sh/blockchain
I recommend this to learn more about Solidity: https://cryptozombies.io/
U can follow Anthony Day on Linekdin
And in general... Google stuff ask chatGPT.
BR, Adam
